# DOM instead of preg_replace?

Tags: php, dom, replace, preg-replace

Just trying to remove two elements with preg_replace but can't get it to work consistently. I would like to remove an element with matching class. Im not used to PHP and i dont know how to use syntax strings. I tried to customize example codes but it doesnt work yet.

Since someone told me to use DOM instead Im totally confused :S

```
<?php

$url = "http://competitive.euw.leagueoflegends.com/de/ladders/euw/current/ranked_team_3x3";

preg_match('#<table class="views-table cols-6"[^>]+>[\w\W]*?</table>#i', file_get_contents($url), $match);
var_dump($match);
$html = preg_replace('~<td([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']views-field views-field-roster-json["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</td>#~', '', $html);
$html2 = preg_replace('~<th([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']views-field views-field-roster-json["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</th>#~', '', $html);
?>
```

Comment: What is not working consistently? The DOM is the Document Object Model. In this case it would definitely be far easier to use with less potential for breakage. You may also want to look at a library like jquery which makes finding and manipulating parts in the DOM.

Comment: The last two lines doest work.

Comment: How can i disable the Array text?